# Chromedriver slow to traverse xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

The following section of my selenium webdriver test written in Java executes very slowly on chromedriver. The whole test normally takes just over three minutes to execute on firefox. However, with chrome it takes more than 8 minutes. The screen of the application is stuck at the screen where the following code is supposed to be executed for more than 75% of the time when using chrome.

Looks like chromedriver is really slow to traverse xpath. Is there a way to get around that and speed up the execution of my test?

Thanks.

```
List<WebElement> RowCount1=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr")); 
System.out.println(RowCount1.size());
for(int i=0;i<RowCount1.size();i++)    
{
       int j=i+1;   
       String product = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr"+"["+j+"]"+"/td[5]")).getText();
            if(product.equalsIgnoreCase(product_name))
            {
                 if(WebDriverFactory.currentBrowser.equals("chrome"))
                   {
                       JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                       jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,700)", "");
                   }
                if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr"+" ["+j+"]"+"/td/input")).isDisplayed())
                {
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr"+"["+j+"]"+"/td/input")).click();
                    report.updateTestLog("addmandatoryproduct", "Active check box is clicked for "+product_name+" ", Status.PASS);
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr"+"["+j+"]"+"/td[2]/input")).click();
                    report.updateTestLog("addmandatoryproduct", "Mandatory check box is clicked for "+product_name+" ", Status.PASS);
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr"+"["+j+"]"+"/td[3]/input")).sendKeys(sequence);
                    report.updateTestLog("addmandatoryproduct", "Sequence check box is updated for "+product_name+" ", Status.PASS);
                break;  
                }   
            }

    }
```

Comment: What is the output of `System.out.println(RowCount1.size());`?

Comment: it changes everytime as a product is added to the list before we get to this section. The current output is 288.

Comment: I was thinking it was because of the row number of the `webtable`. But, since you mentioned same test is faster on `Firefox` I am confuse now. My experience says `Chrome` is the fastest.